# Rails 4 routes namespace / concern with url variables or parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have an app that has some annoyingly specific routes for the calendar section of the app.  They look like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  ...
  day_constraints = { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{1,2}/, day: /\d{1,2}/ }
  get 'days/:month/:day/:year', to: 'schedule#day', constraints: day_constraints, as: :schedule_day
  get 'days/:month/:day/:year/print', to: 'schedule#day_print', constraints: day_constraints
  get 'days/:month/:day/:year/route', to: 'routes#index', constraints: day_constraints
  ...
end
```

As you can see there's a lot of duplication here. They all route to the schedule controller. I was wondering if there is a way to reduce duplication. I was thinking of a namespace or a concern that looks like this:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  ...
  day_constraints = { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{1,2}/, day: /\d{1,2}/ }
  namespace 'days/:month/:day/:year' constraints: day_contstraints do
    get 'print', to: 'schedule#day_print'
    get 'route', to: 'routes#index'

    root to: 'schedule#day'
  end
  ...
end
```

But that throws an error:

```
'day/:month/:day/:year/schedule' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems.
```

Any recommendations for how to clean this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `scope` instead of `namespace` and `get "/" => "schedule#day"` instead of `root to: 'schedule#day'`:

```
day_constraints = { year: /\d{4}/, month: /\d{1,2}/, day: /\d{1,2}/ }
scope 'days/:month/:day/:year', constraints: day_constraints do
  get 'print', to: 'schedule#day_print'
  get 'route', to: 'routes#index'
  get '/', to: 'schedule#day'
end
```

I also had to add a comma between the scope and constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but that's not totally true. You can use `root` on a namespace as well. The same app does it in fact. It just roots to the base of the namespace. So if you have a `namespace :schedule` and give it a `root to: 'schedule#index'` then `schedule_root_path` will send you to `/schedule`. @jvperrin

Comment: @johnnyPando I have updated my answer and tested it in a real application so it should work fine now.